# how to disable the browser forward button and i have script for disable the back...?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

The below code is for disabling the back button in browser.

```
onload="noBack();" onpageshow="if (event.persisted) noBack();" onunload=""

<script type = "text/javascript" >
     window.history.forward();
     function noBack() {
         window.history.forward();
         window.onload = window.history.forward(0);
         window.onbeforeunload = function () { return "You work will be lost."; };
     }
</script>
```

I can't do it for the forward button.

Comment: What do you mean by _"you can't do it"_?

Comment: Why would you want to "disable" the forward button? That code really does not disable a button, all it does is let the page load and than forces them to the next page if there is one.

Comment: Try this link http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-disable-browser-back-and-forward-button1

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in javascript

```
    <script type = 'text/javascript' >
        function changeHashOnLoad() {
           window.location.href += '#';
           setTimeout('changeHashAgain()', '50'); 
        }
        function changeHashAgain() {
            window.location.href += '1';
        }
        var storedHash = window.location.hash;
        window.setInterval(function () {
        if (window.location.hash != storedHash) {
            window.location.hash = storedHash;
         }
         }, 50);
         window.onload=changeHashOnLoad;
   </script>
```

Alternate method

```
<SCRIPT type='text/javascript'>
    window.history.forward();
    function noBack() {window.history.forward(); }
    window.onload=noBack;
    window.onpageshow=function(evt){if(evt.persisted)noBack()}
    window.onunload=function(){void(0)}
</SCRIPT>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: `window.onload='noBack()';` <-- wrong way of assigning a method to the event listener

Comment: And it is still wrong after your edit. You are not calling the method and assigning what it returns to the eventListener. Should be `window.onload = noBack;` and better yet `window.addEventistener("load", noBack);`, but in the end, the code is useless if forward() was called already before.